# how to set iphone app valid for a year?

Tags: iphone, invalidation

I want my app to be invalidated 1 year after the first installation. I am using a webservice for storing device id for apns and thought about storing the first install date with it. but i thought maybe there is a way/method for setting a validation period at sdk or at app store while submitting the app. Is there any simple way for this?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: This depends upon why u wanna invalidate the app. One specific way is to put a value of install date in the storage(userdefaults or plist file) and access it everytime you launch app and compare.

Comment: I want it because i want the user to pay again if he/she wants to use the app one more year. Aren't the plist file and userdefaults reseted when the app is reinstalled?so it seems the JustSid's solution (in app purchase) is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via an in app purchases. But this works only if the user should be allowed to re-activate your app.
There is a special type of in app purchase for abonnements.

Answer (score 2):

Your app will be invalidated even before anyone can install it. Apple will most likely reject it.

[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 2.9 Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected
>
> 11.9 Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected

Comment: "11.9 Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected" so can't i use in app purchase for extending/ending app's life time?

Comment: @xenep - Yes, the application must be minimally functional at all times.  Time limits are not allowed, as per 11.9 above.